# Brightway2 : import Simapro dataset with water resource locations

Tags: python, brightway

I'm importing a Simapro dataset and I plan to resolve the unlinked exchanges by applying a strategy that translate them into existing ones in "biosphere3" database.

The problem is that some water exchanges have specific locations like :

```
Water, well, BR (resource:in water)
Water, unspecified natural origin, OCE (resource:in water)
```

[example of simapro exchanges and their translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Vj0.png)

I would like to keep the specific resources/emissions locations and potentially use them with regionalized LCIA methods like Impact World+.

I know how to specifiy location to technosphere dataset but not to a biosphere dataset. How could I do that ? With "bw2-regional" (https://brightway2-regional.readthedocs.io/index.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar in the past. I can confirm, that you can perform regional LCIA calculations using the brightway2 package (without using `bw2-regional` package). I have done so for a regional water stress method. However, this entails quite a bit of work. In the following a rough description of what I did (feel free to ask more specific questions):

### 1. Import regional lcia method

As biosphere3 does not contain regional (water) flows, I first imported my regional lcia method. I created my own importer, but you can probably also create one based on the `LCIAImporter` class, which will allow you to use the `add_missing_cfs()` function to add new biosphere flows for all the regional characterisation factors of you method. For biopshere flows you can specify the location by adding a new 'location' key to the dictionary object to store the regional identifier.

### 2. Import simapro database

Only after your biosphere contains all the regional flow you want to keep in your simapro database, you can try to create a new strategy that links the flows of your database to those you created in your biosphere. Note that the `SimaProCSVImporter` performs many strategies that will change the biosphere flows in you LCI, which would have to be altered (but I suspect this is the part you already worked on).

Alternatively, you could also import you database using the current brightway2 functions. Afterwards you could try to re-link the biosphere flows you want to regionalise to those new ones you added to your biosphere. The `wurst` package could come in handy.

### bw2-regional

With regard to the `bw2-regional` package I have no experience working with it, but I think it allows for much more complex regional LCA calculations than what you might be used to from simapro.

Comment: Thank you the steps are very clear. I have questions about regionalisation of the LCIA methods but it is a more specific subject so I opened a new question post here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/65953403/15094125
If you have some ideas :)