# Brigthway2 : How to add location specific cfs to an LCIA method

Tags: python, brightway

I know how to create or load an LCIA Method and add cfs to it (see : [How can one save a new LCIA method in Brightway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270469/how-can-one-save-a-new-lcia-method-in-brightway) ).

I would like to load an existing LCIA method and :

1. assign a default location to already existing cfs
2. add new cfs with their specific locations

I think the first point is optional as a defaut location is already set to 'GLO' but I'm also wondering in the case I want to change the default location to e.g. 'EU'.

How should I do ? Does it involve mapping/geomapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question a few weeks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64934341/error-when-validating-impact-assessment-method-data-and-issues-with-regional-cha). You can look at the [example notebook](https://github.com/pbaustert/bw2_reg_cfs/blob/main/notebooks/regionalisation_demo.ipynb) I posted, which shows the issues I encountered.

While I think that there must be a better way, you could simply omit adding regional identifiers to you cfs (as long as they link to the correct regional biosphere flows).